# How do I create a Print Method that is called in the Main method that prints an array in reverse?

Tags: java

Im working with stacks as an assignment and I am able to do the generic pop, push, and peek as required.  I am not able to print however?  The professor I am working with is doing things differently from how I was taught in my last class, so I am not sure how to go about what he wants.  I have tried asking him but it usually ends in me being more confused and him sounding condescending because I did not take his class and did not learn what exactly his other students did.  I have a series of methods to manipulate the char stack.  I am supposed to call pop, peek, and push from the main method to add and view it.  The professor also wants a print method however but I am unsure of how to do it. Here is what I have so far;

```java
public class StackChar {

    //data
    private static int size;
    private static int top;
    private static char[] data;

    public StackChar() {
    }

    public StackChar(int sz) {
        size = sz;
        top = -1;
        data = new char[size];
    }

    /**
     * Description:  This method will push an item onto the top of the stack
     */

    public void push(char letter) {
        if (top != size - 1) {
            top += 1;
            data[top] = letter;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Stack Is Full");
        }
    }

    public char pop() {
        char let1;
        if (top >= 0) {
            let1 = data[top];
            top--;
            return (let1);
        }
        System.out.println("Error: Stack Is Empty");
        return (char)-1;
    }

    public char peek() {
        char let1;
        if (top >= 0) {
            let1 = data[top];
            return (let1);
        }

        System.out.println("Error: Stack Is Empty");
        return (char)-1;
    }

    public static void prints(char[] sc) {
        if (top == -1) {
            System.out.println("Error: Stack Is Empty");
            return;
        }


        for (int i = size - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            System.out.println(letterStack[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackChar sc = new StackChar(10);

        //after each stack method push, pop, peek, you will use prints().

        sc.push('a');
        sc.push('b');
        sc.push('c');
        prints(sc);
        sc.prints();

        //push 6 a-f letters of alphabet in normal order
        //THEN
        //push the next letter of alphabet
        //THEN
        //pop 1
        //push the next letter of the alphabet
        //pop 2
        //push the next letter of the alphabet
        //pop 3
        //peek and print what the peek gives
    }

}
```

My problem lies in the print method, and calling the print method from the Main method.  I am used to simply calling the method on whatever I need it on; `sc.print()` for example.  This does not seem to want to work and I am not sure why.  I also tried changing the print method so that it took the stack as an argument and calling the print method and putting the array into it, but that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: Why you confuse yourself with the main method? This is just a method to start your program... You created an object of your class and you make calls on the methods of this class. So what is your problem with the main method? I ask because you mention the main method many times...

Comment: I don't see where letterStack is declared?

Comment: And a follow-up question... Your main method is inside your class... And all your fields/methods are static. Why you are creating an object? Call the methods directly. A good idea is to separate your class from the Main class. The way you have it, is like calling the same class from its main method.

Comment: +  prints method accepts a char array as a parameter, not a StackChar object.

Comment: Corret your compile time issues and will work and can use I.D.E to learn your error in the code

Comment: @Dren  I forgot to change it back to sc.  I originally had changed the name of what was being inputted thinking maybe there was a conflict there.  I changed it back to sc

Comment: @Aristotle my problem is I am used to calling print in the main method a different way, but because of how this professor wants his code set up, I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Your data structures should not be static unless the methods that use the data is static.

Answer (score -1):

```
public final class StackChar {

    private int top = -1;
    private final char[] data;

    public StackChar(int size) {
        data = new char[size];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return top + 1;
    }

    public void push(char ch) {
        requireNotFull();
        data[++top] = ch;
    }

    public char pop() {
        requireNotEmpty();
        return data[top--];
    }

    public char element() {
        requireNotEmpty();
        return data[top];
    }

    private void requireNotFull() {
        if (top == data.length - 1)
            throw new RuntimeException("Stack Is Full");
    }

    private void requireNotEmpty() {
        if (top == -1)
            throw new RuntimeException("Stack Is Empty");
    }

    public static void print(StackChar stack) {
        System.out.print('[');

        for (int i = 0; i <= stack.top; i++) {
            if (i > 0)
                System.out.print(',');
            System.out.print(stack.data[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(']');
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        StackChar stack = new StackChar(10);

        stack.push('a');
        stack.push('b');
        stack.push('c');
        print(stack);   // [a,b,c]
        stack.push('a');
        stack.push('b');
        stack.push('c');
        stack.push('d');
        stack.push('e');
        stack.push('f');
        print(stack);   // [a,b,c,a,b,c,d,e,f]
        stack.push('g');
        print(stack);   // [a,b,c,a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
        stack.pop();    // g
        print(stack);   // [a,b,c,a,b,c,d,e,f]
        stack.push('h');
        print(stack);   // [a,b,c,a,b,c,d,e,f,h]
        stack.pop();    // h
        stack.pop();    // f
        print(stack);   // [a,b,c,a,b,c,d,e]
        stack.pop();    // e
        stack.pop();    // d
        stack.pop();    // c
        print(stack);   // [a,b,c,a,b]
    }

}
```